# Jest: mock high order function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, integration-testing

I'm trying to mock a third party library to write a integration test using Jest

Prod. code section:

```
const processedContent = await remark().use(html).process(content);
```

So I want to mock remark as a HOF to return a function (use) to return another function (process)

My approach:

```
remark.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return function use() {
        return function process() {
          return testMessageContent;
        };
      };
    })
```

So if console.log(remark) I can see how it returns a function, but when I try to console.log(remark().use(), I'm getting:

```
TypeError: (0 , _remark.default)(...).use is not a function

  72 |     //const ans = await addReply(content, comment, userInfo._id);
  73 | 
> 74 |     console.log(remark().use());
```

And if I:

```
const use = remark()
const process = use()
const message = process()
```

Everything works fine. I'm not getting why this dont work. Any help will be trully appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The mock doesn't return an object with `use` method and that named function is called `use` doesn't change the way it works.

It should be:

```
remark.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return { use() {
        return { process() {
          return testMessageContent;
        } };
      } };
    })
```

Comment: You are totally right, it worked, but I'm not getting why you don't need to declare both use() and process() function implementation. It is getting wrapped by the original module? 
Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Glad it worked. `{ use() { ...` is the short syntax for `{ use: function use() { ... }` object literal, in case this what you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur answer! Really newbie to JS!